# Spring security 3 intercept-url pattern with index

Tags: regex, spring, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security v3.2 for a project. At the moment I always use a coldfusion file that calls other files to build up the view. So all my urls go trough `index.cfm?blablah`.

Now I am stuck with allowing the anonymous user enter the home view. Following [Spring Security request matcher is not working with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503944/spring-security-request-matcher-is-not-working-with-regex?answertab=votes#tab-top), I made up the this code:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="^.*index.cfm\?action=home.*$" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/root/index.cfm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login />
</http>
```

But whatever I try, I always enter the login field.

Comment: It's normal, your rules say to always enter the login field. Look your last rule. Have you test your regex out of intercept-url ? I think, why not, such as that: `<http pattern="^.*index.cfm\?action=home.*$" security="none"/>`

Comment: Just saw your answer after finding it out myself. But you also need a request-matcher attribute, as the request-matcher is default at 'ant'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more trying I found a solution:

```
<http request-matcher="regex" pattern="^.*index.cfm\?action=home.*$" security="none"/>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/root/index.cfm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/root/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login />
 </http>
```