# GWT - Spring security url intercepting

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security

I am using GWT and url for my incharge page as

> *http://www.example.com/backend.html?locale=en&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1%3A9997#incharge*

I would like to check this url with **Spring Role Authorization**. I used in my spring-security.xml as below

```
<sec:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticateFilterEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/unSecure.html">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="#incharge" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout.html" logout-success-url="/login.html" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.html"
            login-processing-url="/login_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=1"/>

    <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.html">
        <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="50" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </sec:session-management>
    <sec:remember-me key="TBdqj219ab910lsAc12" token-validity-seconds="604800"/>
</sec:http>
```

But always pass and spring security filter was not bind. Please help me how to check user's role when given url contain ***#incharge*** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was long time since I do not use Spring, but seeing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503944/spring-security-request-matcher-is-not-working-with-regex), the pattern attr looks like powerful.

I am just guessing but probably if you do something like:

`pattern="^.*#incharge$"`, should work.

From my point of view the pattern is the key here. I am not sure if Spring internally respects the hash, but it is worth to try.

:)